# Gnuplot is not clearing data between plots

Tags: perl, gnuplot

I'm writing a perl program which calls gnuplot multiple times to plot and fit separate data sets, by writing out a Gnuplot command string datasets and then invoking gnuplot, aiming it at the data file. To avoid filling the disc with junk, I reuse the same data file name each time.

Despite trying to clear everything between calls (by issuing a "del puts.cmnds" order, gnuplot appends the new data to the old data. I can't delete the files between cases, because it is "still open" in the gnuplot program.

Here is the gnuplot program, as defined in perl:

```
$commandString= "val(x) = a + b*x + c*x*x
fit val(x) 'puts.data' using 1:2 via a,b,c 
set title 'Puts'
plot 'puts.data' with linespoints, a + b*x + c*x*x 
pause -1 
set print 'putabc.txt'
print a,b,c
clear";
    # End of multiline quote
```

Here is the code that writes out the data:

```
$cmndFileName="put.cmnds";
open $pfc,">$gpFolder$cmndFileName" or die "$!";
print $pfc $commandString;
close $pfc;
```

Note that I do not open to append, but to overwrite. But it nevertheless appends in the data file.

Here is the command to execute the gnu commands:

```
$ret2 = `cd \\progra~1\\gnuplot\\bin\\ &&  gnuplot -e "" put.cmnds`;
```

I then try to clean everything up:

```
close $pfd;
$dummy = `del $putFile`;
```

How can I get gnuplot to clear the files?
Why does my perl open command appear to append rather than open a new clean file?

Comment: You have not shown all the relevant code. Such as what does $gpFolder abd $putFile contain? Also you say you close $pfd, but your filehandle is called $pfc. You will learn what went wrong when you add `use strict; use warnings;` to your code. Also, since your code is incomplete and cannot be reproduced, you must add relevant information or it will probably be closed due to lack of information.

Comment: You have not shown the gnuplot command used to open an output file.  Normally this is `set output "filename"` and when you are finished with it you close it with `unset output`.  Did you do that?

Comment: I tried to spare you the entire code section, but, if you insist:

Comment: I tried to spare you the entire code section, but, if you insist: OK, I posted it all here, but the post was rejected for being too long by 1963 characters. In any case $pfd & $pfc are the filehandles for the data and command files respectively, As for "setoutput", the problem is not with the output files, but with the input files. Are there a corresponding command to set & unset input files? When I look at them on the disc they contain the concatenated data, so that;s where the problem is

Comment: I see that my repeated open to write commands are not executed since the files are already open and can't be closed since they are in use by the program.

Comment: It would append if `$gpFolder` started with `>`. You shouldn't be using two-arg `open`.

Comment: @user1067305 The point of showing code is not showing all of it, but only enough to demonstrate your problem. Dumping all your code into the question is not enough, you have to work on it.